# Inheritance in MySql

Tags: mysql, inheritance

I need to create a huge table called worker (`id_worker` is the primary key) and lots of other columns like `name`, `date_of_birth`, etc.

I also need to create several other tables that inherit this one (all the different kinds of workers from the company). They all have the attributes from worker (`name`, `date_of_birth`) and also the same primary key (`id_worker`).

I read that I cannot do this in MySQL because it does not support inheritance. How do I do it then?

Comment: I don't understand what you're actually trying to do

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you could use regular joins to get the same effect.

Comment: You can do inheritance with any sql and there are a few ways to do it; the best being dependent on the problem (single table with views or multi-tabled, for example). If they all have the same *exact* fields and no additional ones you're essentially just needing a column for `employeeType`. I would probably make an enumerated table for those so it's extensible.

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TABLE workers(id INT(11) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(64), date_of_birth DATE);
CREATE TABLE worker_type(id INT(11) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(64));
CREATE TABLE workers_types(worker_id INT(11) NOT NULL, woker_type_id INT(11) NOT NULL);

SELECT workers.name, worker_type.name FROM workers
LEFT JOIN workers_types ON workers_types.worker_id = workers.id
LEFT JOIN worker_type ON worker_type.id = workers_types.worker_type_id;
```

Sorry not proofed and bad naming...